# Merge multi dimensional array preserving keys not working

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have following two arrays

```
$array1 = array (
  'MB04' => 
  array (
    78 => 
    array (
      2 => '30',
      1 => '30',
    ),
  ),
);

$array2 = array (
  'MB04' => 
  array (
    78 => 
    array (
      3 => '25',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I want to merge two arrays so that the final array looks like

```
$finalArray = array (
  'MB04' => 
  array (
    78 => 
    array (
      2 => '30',
      1 => '30',
      3 => '25'
    ),
  ),
);
```

I have used the following approaches but it's not working:

```
# Approach 1
var_dump(array_merge($array1, $array2));

# Approach 2
var_dump($array1 + $array2);

# Approach 3
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

I want to achieve the final array with the native function (minimal code) if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution using [array_replace_recursive](https://www.php.net/array_replace_recursive)

```
# Approach 4
var_dump(array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array ( 'MB04' => array ( 78 => array ( 2 => '30', 1 => '30', ), ), );

$array2 = array ( 'MB04' => array ( 78 => array ( 3 => '25', ), ), );


$result['MB04'][78] =$array1['MB04'][78]+$array2['MB04'][78];
print_r($result);
```

Comment: $array1 & $array2 are dynamic so it cannot be hard-coded.